# Create a form to activate user permission

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want a django form which is an instance of a User and get an html form as constitued by radio buttons to activate or deactivate a permission.

A html code of this kind is expected at the end:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="change_user">Can edit user:</label>
    <div class="labeled" id="change_user">
        <input class="with-gap" name="change_user_False" type="radio" id="change_user_False" value="False">
        <label for="change_user_False">No</label>
        <input class="with-gap" name="change_user_True" type="radio" id="change_user_True" value="True" checked="">
        <label for="change_user_True">Yes</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The example permission here will be "change_user" and the goal is to handle all the process in a clean django form. I do not know what is the most appropriate way...

Use on a simple form and manage everything in the clean function by passing in parameter a User object.

```
from django import forms

class PermissionForm(forms.Form):
    change_user = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=((True, 'No'), (False, 'Yes')), required=True)

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.fields['change_user'].initial = select_user.has_permission('auth.change_user ')

     def clean(self, select_user):
         if self.cleaned_data['change_user']:
              select_user.permissions.add('change_user')
```

Or use a form of the User instance:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []
        widget = ...
```

But how to generate a widget in radioselect on a permission and catch errors when returned data wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your question using Django `UpdateView` with a `ModelForm` like this example (See the comments in order to understand what's going on):

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from YOUR_APP_NAME import models

class UserPermissionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    change_user = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'no')],
        required=True  # It's required ?
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.YOUR_MODEL_NAME
        fields = ('change_user',)  # I'll use only one field
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission 
from YOUR_APP_NAME import models, forms


class UserPermissionView(UpdateView):
    model = models.YOUR_MODEL_NAME
    template_name = 'user_permission.html' # Your template name
    form_class = forms.UserPermissionsForm
    initial = {}  # We'll update the form's fields by their initial values

    def get_initial(self):
        """Update the form_class's fields by their initials"""

        base_initial = super().get_initial()
        # Here we'll check if the user has the permission of 'change_user'
        user_has_permission = self.request.user.user_permissions.filter(
            codename='change_user'
        ).first()
        base_initial['change_user'] = True if user_has_permission else False
        return base_initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Here we'll update the user's permission based on the form choice:
        If we choose: Yes => Add 'change_user' permission to the user
                      No => Remove 'change_user' permission from the user
        """
        change_user = form.cleaned_data['change_user']
        permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='change_user')
        if change_user == 'True':
            self.request.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
            # Use django's messaging framework
            # We'll render the results into the template later
            messages.success(
                self.request,
                'Updated: User [{}] Can change user'.format(self.request.user.username)
            )
        else:
            self.request.user.user_permissions.remove(permission)
            messages.success(
                self.request,
                'Updated: User [{}] Cannot change user'.format(self.request.user.username)
            )
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        """
           Don't forget to add your success URL,
           basically use the same url's name as this class view
        """
        # Note here, we'll access to the URL based on the user pk number
        return reverse_lazy('user_permissions', kwargs={'pk': self.request.user.pk})
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from YOUR_APP_NAME import views


urlpatterns = [
    path(
           'client/<int:pk>/',  # Access the view by adding the User pk number
           views.UserPermissionView.as_view(), 
           name='user_permissions'
    ),
    ... # The rest of your paths
]
```

And finally the template:

**user_permissions.html:**

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}
    {% endfor %}
    <br><br>
{% endif %}

<div>User: {{ user.username }}</div>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here are some screenshots of the flow of this solution:

[image: First]

[image: second]

[image: third]

And of course, you can check if the add/remove actions of the permission under the Django Admin Panel.

Comment: It's very close of what I want to do. But when I use `fields = ('change_user',)` (like you) I get the fallowing error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (change_user) specified for User` because `User` don't directly have a `change_user` value... That my problem when I try ModelForm way.

Comment: try with `__all__` and then tell me do use django's `User` model directly or do you use a foreignkey/`OneToOneField` to `User` model ?

Comment: I directly use the model Django `User` model. I can call any permission in true the relation OneToMany (defined by the django framework for permissions) to apply a widget on them... And that make no sense to create a `ModelForm` with use fields and widgets. I think I need to handle all the process (a bit like you did) in a `Form`.